# Presto SQL to select all records between the current date/time and 36 hours ago

Tags: sql, presto, starburst

I'd prefer not to update two date string each morning and simply select all records between now and the previous 36 hours. Sample where condition which I would like to paramaterise:

```
-- DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(desk.reported_date, 'UTC'), '%Y-%m-%d %T') BETWEEN '2024-01-02 06:00:00.000' AND '2024-12-31 23:59:59.000'
```

My attempts:

```
 --DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(desk.submit_date, 'UTC'),'%Y-%m-%d %T') > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '36' HOUR)
 --CAST (DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(desk.submit_date, 'UTC'),'%Y-%m-%d %T') AS DATE)        > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' HOUR 
   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(desk.submit_date, 'UTC'), '%Y-%m-%d %T') BETWEEN  '2024-01-02 06:00:00.000' AND date_add('hour', desk.submit_date, date_parse(-36, '%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Common Error:

```
Cannot subtract hour, minutes or seconds from a date
```

Comment: When using DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(desk.reported_date, 'UTC'), '%Y-%m-%d %T')  BETWEEN current_timestamp - interval '36' hour AND current_timestamp
I'm getting Error  Cannot check if varchar is BETWEEN timestamp(3) with time zone and timestamp(3) with time zone. Can these interval functions be used when UTC is in play?

Comment: This was resolved by setting the field type (FROM_UNIXTIME) and applying the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INTERVAL` to get your wanted data.

If you want to manipute the timestamp current_timestamp (with timezone), you need as result again a timestampo

```
WHERE desk.submit_date BETWEEN current_timestamp - interval '36' hour AND current_timestamp
```